# Next Js error Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <body> in <div>

Tags: next.js

Facing this issue.
I want to add class in body tag using next js.
Here is what i am doing right now. but that generate error.

This is generating 2 body tags in source code.
How can i add custom style class to body tag while not generating 2 body tags in code which causing the error.

```
<body className="lines">
    <Layout>
      <NextProgress />
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Suspense>
    </Layout>
    </body>
```

Comment: Where do you have the code you pasted?

Comment: Its in next js root _document file.